# workbox service worker with webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker, workbox

Currently, I am trying to cache api call with service worker. It does cache the api request. However, it does not seems to take advantage of caching. 
When I check the network tab on devtool, I see request from service worker and workbox both of them and even slower than normal request.

I tried older version with webpack 3, cached api returns almost instantly like 3ms.

[image]
[image]

Before there was not second call on

**workbox-webpack-plugin config**

```
new workboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
  swDest: 'sw.js',
  clientsClaim: true,
  skipWaiting: true,
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: new RegExp('/'),
      handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
    },
    {
      urlPattern: new RegExp('https://api/'),
      handler: 'cacheFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'api',
        expiration: {
          maxEntries: 100,
          maxAgeSeconds: 72 * 60 * 60
        },
        cacheableResponse: { statuses: [0, 200] },
      }
    },
  ]
```

})

Service worker request create some kind of bottle neck ?

Side question - whats difference between 2 period of time in network request ? as you see from image there is 3.53s and 2.01s on first request

Comment: Is your code anywhere on Github or hosted online somewhere? Would make debugging a little easier.

The above should work, although there was a bug that was fixed in v3.1.0 that might fix this problem.

Comment: Workbox had some bug on that but its fixed now